# How do uploaded photos and files impact search performance?

Tags: performance

I am creating a Drupal site where performance is a key goal and have a few questions:

- Does Drupal store the photos in the same table as the rest of the node's fields?
- Will enabling photo uploads on nodes adversely impact search performance any more than other conventional field types? (text etc) If the answer to the above question is yes but it does not negatively impact search performance, why not?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Drupal store the photos in the same table as the rest of the
>   node's fields?

Well, no. In fact Drupal stores all fields in their own table. I suppose you could have figured this out by yourself by just looking into the database.

> Will enabling photo uploads on nodes adversely impact search
>   performance any more than other conventional field types?

I cannot see how it would; an image does not contain text. It would be pretty useless of Drupal to search through the image's binary data. If are unsure and do not trust it, you can always use the [search api module](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api), which allows you to select which fields you want to index and search.